# INDEX MATCH formula stops working when creating a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have the folowing values setup in excel:

```
1 | 2 | 3 |

a | b | c |
```

Above thess values I have a `INDEX MATCH` formula that looks up a translation of the numbers 1-3:

```
=INDEX(PartnersProjects[Name];MATCH(K1;PartnersProjects[ID];0))
```

K1` is the reference to value "1" and picks up "Test1" with current output:

```
Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |
  1   |   2   |   3   |
  a   |   b   |   c   |
```

But when I convert the 2 rows with according 3 colums (1-3 and a-c) to a table, the formula in the row above stops working some how. How to solve this?

Comment: What are `PartnersProjects[Name]` and `PartnersProjects[ID]`?

Comment: PartnersProjects is a table in another tab that I have. Id and Name are the references where "1" (in column Id) corresponds with the name "Test1" (in column Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make the row `1, 2, 3` as the header row of a table, this forces Excel to evaluate it as a string because these becomes the **names** of the columns.

You have two solutions:

1- Convert the searched value (`K1`) to numeric before matching:

```
=INDEX(PartnersProjects[Name],MATCH(VALUE(K1),PartnersProjects[ID],0))
'                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

2- Convert the search range to text, but then you will need an ^array (CSE) formula:

```
=INDEX(PartnersProjects[Name],MATCH(K1,TEXT(PartnersProjects[ID], "0"),0))
' Ctrl+Shift+Enter                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @pnuts lol as I guessed this "above" was mistakenly stated. Unless some Excel versions have row 0 :P